# command to compile c++ program on live Fedora

Tags: c++, linux, command

I'm using Fedora 20 live with the help of a DVD instead of installing it. I have used the following command to compile c++ program:

```
g++ programname.cpp
```

But it displayed this:

```
bash: g++: command not found...
```

Is there any other alternative command?
Why g++ command is not working for me? 
Is using Live Fedora the reason??

Comment: This means g++ has not been installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try c++, which is usually a symlink to the currently installed C++ compiler. If you don't have that, try clang++.

The g++ command is part of the GNU C/C++ compiler gcc. Using the g++ command specifies that you want to compile a C++ program, but it's actually just a link to the gcc command. Try using gcc instead of g++. You may have problems with that because it will try to compile it as a C program, but I think there is a compiler flag that will force it to compile it as a C++ program. If none of this works, then you probably don't have a compiler installed. I am not familiar with Fedora's package manager, but the package you want will probably be called either gcc or g++.